# Adding a "space" value to a char in Java

Tags: java, string, char

By space I mean the following:

```
myString = ""; //This string is empty. It is not what I am talking about.
myString = " "; //This string has one space. It is what I am talking about.
```

Now, I tried to asign a space to a char by doing the following:

```
char myChar = " ";
```

And I got the following error:

```
incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char.
```

Based on this I guess whatever is inside quotation marks is always considered a String in Java (please correct me if I am wrong). Right now I am just doing the following, and it works:

```
String emptyStr = " ";
char empty = emptyStr.charAt(0); //Tested it and the char does take a space value.
```

My question is the following. **Is there a more efficient or already predetermined way to do this?**

Comment: `" "` is a `String` not a `Char`.

Comment: `char myChar = ' ';` That's by default. Note the single quotes.

Comment: maybe you should start consulting the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/index.html) instead of guessing... kind of essential to underestand the primitive types and literals.

Comment: Oops. I now feel sorry my question is taking unnecessary space in the webpage´s server. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding you are trying to assign space value in to char type .But the value you given is a string and trying to assign in to a char type .if u want to assign a space character do it by using ' '.

```
char mychar=" "; //wont works because you are assigning  a string type in to char type
```

but

```
char mychar=' ';//this will work because assigning a char type in to char type
```